# Extract Tree built-in filter to separate input

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am currently developing an app with Primefaces and recently started using a Tree component. It exactly provide the functionality that I need but I have some problems while using it inside of a dialog. When there are many records I had to surround this tree with `<p:outputPanel>` in order to have scroll. Everything was fine until I added filtering to that tree component. Because of surrounded panel this filter input text appears right above the tree, inside of this panel and when I scroll this down, this filter input is left above on top.

Is there a possibility that I add manually a filter input above the whole panel and connect it to the tree like it is done for example in DataTable components of PrimeFaces? Tried that way yet it is not working. Below is .xhtml of my dialog. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <p:dialog id="manageKnownDeviceDlg" header="#{msg['ip.usb.manageKnownDlg.Title']}" height="700"
              showEffect="explode" resizable="true" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)"
              width="700" widgetVar="manageKnownDeviceDlg" style="text-align: right;">
        <h:form id="manageKnownDialogForm" >
            <p:outputPanel style="width: 100%; max-height: 600px; min-height: 600px;height: 88%;overflow: auto;display: block; border: solid 1px;">
                <p:tree id="manageKnownDevicesTree" var="knownDevice" value="#{baseModel.usbDeviceDictTreeRoot}"
                        widgetVar="usbDeviceDictTree"
                        selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{baseModel.usbDeviceDictSelected}"
                        filterBy="#{knownDevice}" filterMatchMode="contains" emptyMessage="#{msg['global.noData']}"
                        style="text-align: left; width: 98%;">
                    <p:treeNode>
                        <h:outputText value="#{knownDevice.toString()}"/>
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <br/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="position: absolute; right: 5px;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="5" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['ip.usb.manageKnownDlg.Disable']}" update="manageKnownDevicesTree"
                                     actionListener="#{knownDevicesDlgController.unselectKnownDeviceClasses}" styleClass="vs-button"
                                     process="manageKnownDeviceDlg"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['ip.usb.manageKnownDlg.YesToAll']}" update="manageKnownDevicesTree"
                                     actionListener="#{knownDevicesDlgController.selectAllDevices}" styleClass="vs-button"
                                     process="manageKnownDeviceDlg"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['ip.usb.manageKnownDlg.NoToAll']}" update="manageKnownDevicesTree"
                                     actionListener="#{knownDevicesDlgController.unselectAllDevices}" styleClass="vs-button"
                                     process="manageKnownDeviceDlg"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['global.ok']}" update="usbForm:usbDeviceTable,manageKnownDialogForm"
                                     onclick="PF('manageKnownDeviceDlg').hide();" process="manageKnownDeviceDlg" styleClass="vs-button"
                                     actionListener="#{knownDevicesDlgController.addKnownDevice}" style="text-align: right"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['global.cancel']}" update="manageKnownDeviceDlg" styleClass="vs-button"
                                     onclick="PF('manageKnownDeviceDlg').hide();"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: You could try some (jquery) dom manipulation to move the **client-side** html filters out of the panel... or try http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/moveComponent

Comment: But even better, maybe not using an outputPanel but setting a max-height on .ui-tree-container already solves your problem. I tried in the showcase to set it to 70px and I get a scrollbar in the 'nodes' part and the filter stays at the top

Comment: .ui-tree-container with max-height on does the trick, awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a max-height on the ui-tree-container solves the problem. Using this in the showcase

```
.ui-tree-container {
    max-height: 70px;
}
```

Results in

[image]

You might want to add an explicit class to the tree and use that in the selector so it does not apply to all trees.

Comment: You are welcome. As you see, not everything needs to be solved in a 'jsf' way. it in the end is all html css etc...